# Are these bad eating habits in a 7 month old?

Tags: infant, eating

My 7 month old baby easts enthusiastically, but puts his fingers (index and middle) in his mouth after every spoon. I thought may be he's pushing the food back to his throat, but it doesn't seem like it. He's only letting some drip out. On the few occasions that he doesn't do this, he has no difficulty swallowing his purees.

He also grabs the spoon from our hand and keeps sucking on it for a couple minutes. We first thought that may be this means he's full and just wants to play, but he does it after only a couple spoonsful, and after playing with it for some time, is ready to be fed again.

Are these things bad habits? Why do babies do this? Should I address them, if so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At 7 months old, I take it your child is somewhat new to solids. We take eating for granted, but it's a pretty big deal to someone who has only ever known drinking. It's not a mundane task for infants, it's a very rich experience.

Yes he'll want to feel it with his fingers, let it drip out to feel the sensation of the food in his face, and observe what it looks like after he has chewn on it. Touch and taste won't be enough, he'll also throw it to the floor to hear what it splashes like, or send it flying across the room to investigate its external ballistics.

You say "may be this means he's full and just wants to play". I think he has no conscious plan to become full behind his eating, and is playing throughout the meal.

What should you do? Opinionated answer: encourage him! Allow him to explore and experience. Later on, getting your child to eat will occasionally be a big deal. Make sure the experience of eating is enjoyable.

Comment: Maybe even add to the experience by providing “finger food” and allow him to feed himself?

Comment: Check out “baby led weaning” recipes for some age appropriate finger food ideas.